# How does one reapply window film?

Tags: windows

My wife bought decorative translucent film for our bathroom. Over the last year, it's gradually peeled off until it fell off today. I tried reapplying it, but the curl of the material keeps pulling it off. Is there a viable step, or are we going to have to buy another set of film?

Comment: Change brands if replacing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that they all dry-out & constrict. Of course, you can try taping it up around the perimeter. But, yeah it's a never ending replacement product that's really too expensive to start with. I haven't done it, but there's glass spray paint out there that you might try on a drinking glass to see if that'll work. I'd suspect it lasts a lot longer or forever & may not come off.